# Slider For Website

Tags: asp.net

Am designing a website in Visual Studio 2010,
I have designed the header section of my website. However, now i want to introduce a slider window just below the header section that will dynamically move the content within the window. Kindly help me with the details!
Thank you!

Comment: what u want to display in the slider images/content or both...?

Comment: basically both sir! images would me changing like a slide show! and the content would be moving dynamically to left!!

Comment: ok then go for http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/ u will get code and explanation of code for the slider understand it properly to implement on your web page